# Thorcam C API implementation

Tags: c, windows, matlab

This is kind of noob question since I don't program a lot in C. The problem I have is when using the C API for the DCU 223 camera from Thorlabs. I need to wrap some functions to use the video capabilites reported in the API under Matlab (through some mex files) but when  trying to make some simple examples, using only C,

The program is:

```
#include "uc480.h"
#include "stdio.h"


int main() {

    int * pnc;
    int r = -1;

    r = is_GetNumberOfCameras( pnc );

    if(r == IS_SUCCESS)
        printf("numero de camaras %d", pnc);
    else if(r == IS_NO_SUCCESS)
        printf("numero de camaras %d", pnc);

    return r;
}
```

Where I get this error when compiling

```
In file included from prueba.c:1:0:
uc480.h:3225:5: error: expected identifier before '}' token
} TRANSFER_CAPABILITY_FLAGS;
```

The specific line in uc480.h is:

```
typedef enum E_TRANSFER_CAPABILITY_FLAGS
{
} TRANSFER_CAPABILITY_FLAGS;
```

The video capabilites of the camera are accessible through a library called uc480_toos.h but when I try to call this library from matlab I get a lot of compilation errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Thaks for the attention.